# TO become sitecore developer, what do I need to know? .net MVC or just c#?

Tags: sitecore

I am new to software industry. I am into sitecore field now. I have just basic C# knowledge. I want your help to learn. Could you please help with good ASP.NET mvc tutorial and tutorial for sitecore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest starting with the sitecore.net site and go through the Learn & Get Started section, particularly on training. The e-Learning will help you get an idea of what working with Sitecore is like.

From there, get involved in the community (community.sitecore.net, Slack, etc.) so you have people you can reach out to for help.

Regarding primary language, from Sitecore Stack Exchange: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4853/what-server-side-language-does-sitecore-use

> Sitecore uses either ASP.NET Web Forms or ASP.NET MVC to generate the
>   final HTML pages. This means developers can use any programming
>   language of the .NET Framework. C# is one of the most popular with
>   VB.NET but any other .NET Framework language like F# can be used.
>
> That being said, most if not all Sitecore developers use C#.

In addition, there is a list of resources for those learning:

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-can-i-get-started-learning-sitecore

Comment: Thanks Jay! any good resource for mvc, c#?

Comment: Learning MVC and C# is outside the realm of the 'Sitecore' tag. I would suggest you remove that part of your question to keep your question focused on Sitecore and then search the StackExchange sites for help on C#/MVC materials.

Comment: with respect to sitecore, which one I have to learn asp.net mvc or c#?

Comment: It will depend on what you are planning to do with Sitecore. However,if you are learning .net MVC, you will need C# for any controllers you are writing. You can also do classic Web Forms implementations, but it is no longer recommended.
With some of the APIs, you can also do headless implementation and just consume Sitecore into the platform of your choice. Not a choice for beginners, though, so I would recommend going a more traditional route which the courses will cover.

I will update my answer to contain a link to some content with good "starting up" content.